# Adding more than one model to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing with ASP.NET Core MVC. I have an accordion design on the page displaying what would traditionally be a web page.

Because of this, I need to have multiple models on the page.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel; a class with the single purpose of bringing data to the view

```
public class SampleViewModel {
  public ModelClass1 Model1 {get; set;}
  public IList<ModelClass2> ListOfModel2 {get; set;}
}
```